# writeHeader() still running if appendAllowed set to true?

Tags: java, spring, append, spring-batch, writer

Good day,

I am creating a spring batch that will write output in a text.

Basically the output will be 1 row header and multiple rows of details.

And then, in the xml, I set

```
<property name="appendAllowed" value="true" />
```

for my writer.

And in my writer java file,

```
@Override
public void writeHeader(Writer writer) throws IOException {
   // write header here
}

@Override
public void write(List< ? extends ZakatVO > items) throws Exception {

    List< String > lines = new ArrayList< String >( );
    // generate details here
    this.delegate.write( lines );
}
```

At first I expected if I run again the job, it will append another 1 row of header other multiple rows of details to the same output file.

But what I get is just append the details line.

Is this anything I configure wrongly? Or this is the normal behaviour?

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 1):

Your "writeHeader" code is empty so it won't write any header. You have to explicitly write the header in the method.
Like:

```
@Override
    public void writeHeader(Writer writer) throws IOException {
writer.write("something....");
```

Second you have explicitly disabled append on already existing file, so it won't append anything on the second run.

Comment: Even I didnt put anything inside `writeHeader()`, but it will still append a line right? Because my output is first line is blank, data start at second line.

Comment: Yes if you look at source code in FlatFileItemWriter aftew write header there is this call outputState.write(this.lineSeparator);